# Rails cron job to update status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, cron-task

I'm new to Rails cron job. Here's my question, I have an attribute called `status` and `expiration date`, let's say the `expiration date` is `2017/10/21`, on that particular date, I want to update the `status` from Effect to Due, how am I supposed to do that. So far here's what I know,

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 am' do
 # do something here
end
```

It would be appretiated if somebody points me some direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should filter the records then update them. Something like this:

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 am' do
  Record.where(expiration_date: Date.today)
        .update_all(status: 'due')
end
```